# Airbnb react date range picker only showing current month calendar not selected dates month calender

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, react-dates

I'm trying to add [airbnb-react-date](https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates). After selecting start date and end date when I am re-opening the date picker the calendar shows current month instead of the selected start date/end date's month.

For example: If I set start date = **2017-05-05** and end date = **2017-05-09** then it shows the selected date, but if I click again the calendar picker opens and it only shows current month i.e **February** calendar, that's why I have to click the next month, next month to see the previous selected dates i.e **May**;

**How I implemented:**   From  https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates#getting-started

Installed  `npm install --save react-dates moment@>=#.## react@>=#.## react-dom@>=#.## react-addons-shallow-compare@>=#.##`

I have installed required node packages i.e babel, webpack. Every time I run command `webpack` on the project directory to build the `bundle.js` and then run `index.html` to see the output.

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_datepicker.css"/>
</head>
<body><div id="form" style="height: 400px">
   <h4>Initial date picker</h4>

   <div style="margin-left: 4px" id="mydatepicker"></div>
</div><script async type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**entry.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import moment from 'moment';

import { DateRangePicker } from 'react-dates';


var SelectedStartDate = moment('2017-05-05');
var SelectedEndDate = moment('2017-05-09');


class HomePageDatePicker extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      focusedInput: null,
      startDate: SelectedStartDate,
      endDate:SelectedEndDate
    };
    this.onDatesChange = this.onDatesChange.bind(this);
    this.onFocusChange = this.onFocusChange.bind(this);
  }

  onDatesChange({ startDate, endDate }) {

    this.setState({ startDate, endDate });
  }

  onFocusChange(focusedInput) {
    this.setState({ focusedInput });
  }

  render() {
    const { focusedInput, startDate, endDate } = this.state;
    return (
        <div>
          <DateRangePicker
              {...this.props}
              onDatesChange={this.onDatesChange}
              onFocusChange={this.onFocusChange}
              focusedInput={focusedInput}
              startDate={startDate}
              endDate={endDate}
              startDateId="datepicker_start_home"
              endDateId="datepicker_end_home"
              startDatePlaceholderText="Check In"
              endDatePlaceholderText="Check Out"
              />
        </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <HomePageDatePicker
        />, document.getElementById('mydatepicker')
);
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  entry: "./entry.js",
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style!css" },
      { 
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0', 'react'],
          plugins: ['transform-runtime']
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

**What I Have:**[image]

**What I Need:**

[image]

Comment: always-sunny, is there any way to set a predefined date for this datepicker plugins? If yes, what happen while you try to enforce set a date that you want!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as stated in react-dates [storybook](http://airbnb.io/react-dates/?selectedKind=DateRangePicker%20%28DRP%29&selectedStory=default&full=0&down=1&left=1&panelRight=0&downPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel) you can do this with `initialVisibleMonth={endDate}` on the render function.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import moment from 'moment';

import { DateRangePicker } from 'react-dates';


var SelectedStartDate = moment('2017-05-05');
var SelectedEndDate = moment('2017-05-09');


class HomePageDatePicker extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      focusedInput: null,
      startDate: SelectedStartDate,
      endDate:SelectedEndDate
    };
    this.onDatesChange = this.onDatesChange.bind(this);
    this.onFocusChange = this.onFocusChange.bind(this);
  }

  onDatesChange({ startDate, endDate }) {

    this.setState({ startDate, endDate });
  }

  onFocusChange(focusedInput) {
    this.setState({ focusedInput });
  }

  render() {
    const { focusedInput, startDate, endDate } = this.state;
    return (
        <div>
          <DateRangePicker
              {...this.props}
              onDatesChange={this.onDatesChange}
              onFocusChange={this.onFocusChange}
              focusedInput={focusedInput}
              startDate={startDate}
              endDate={endDate}
              startDateId="datepicker_start_home"
              endDateId="datepicker_end_home"
              startDatePlaceholderText="Check In"
              endDatePlaceholderText="Check Out"
              initialVisibleMonth={endDate}
              />
        </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <HomePageDatePicker
        />, document.getElementById('mydatepicker')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with `numberOfMonths="1"`.

```
     <DateRangePicker
                    startDatePlaceholderText="Check In"
                    endDatePlaceholderText="Check Out"
                    initialVisibleMonth={endDate}
                    displayFormat="DD-MM-YYYY"
                    numberOfMonths="1"
                    startDate={this.state.startDate} // momentPropTypes.momentObj or null,
                    startDateId="your_unique_start_date_id" // PropTypes.string.isRequired,
                    endDate={this.state.endDate} // momentPropTypes.momentObj or null,
                    endDateId="your_unique_end_date_id" // PropTypes.string.isRequired,
                    onDatesChange={({ startDate, endDate }) => this.setState({ startDate, endDate })} // PropTypes.func.isRequired,
                    focusedInput={this.state.focusedInput} // PropTypes.oneOf([START_DATE, END_DATE]) or null,
                    onFocusChange={focusedInput => this.setState({ focusedInput })} // PropTypes.func.isRequired,
                    initialVisibleMonth={this.state.endDate}
                    
                />
```